# Figuring out the @ symbol in this context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/blob/master/examples/04%20Sortable/Simple/Card.js

I'm trying to figure out what the @ symbol in this example means.

It's supposed to be a simple drag and drop example, but having the examples in i'm assuming ES7 is throwing me off and I can't follow what this is doing.. or how to translate it to ES6

If someone could rewrite this part in ES6 just so i can understand it, that would be great.

```
@DropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD, cardTarget, connect => ({
  connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
}))
@DragSource(ItemTypes.CARD, cardSource, (connect, monitor) => ({
  connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
  isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
}))
export default class Card extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    connectDragSource: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    connectDropTarget: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    isDragging: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    id: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    moveCard: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };
```

Comment: This is not part of ES7 (ES2016). It's an experimental feature, so it's not part of any version yet.

Comment: @FelixKling so is that just part of the library then?

Comment: Not exactly. They are probably using a preprocessor like Babel to convert the code to valid JS. As I said l, it's an experimental feature (proposal) so it might make it into the language one day, but it's impossible to know when (atm).

Comment: That decorator syntax is described in the [README](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/tree/master/examples) of the github repo you linked.

Comment: thanks guys appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

The @ sign is usually referred to as a Decorator (similar to Annotations in Java). It is used to tell the parser that you're using a decorator.

A decorator is used to add additional functionality to an existing function without having to modify it. The above decorates takes an additional argument which is the function being decorated and returns the same function with additional functionality.

> Wrap your component with DropTarget to make it react to the compatible items being dragged, hovered, or dropped on it. DropTarget is a higher-order component.

[DropTarget Documentation](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drop-target.html)

> Wrap your component with DragSource to make it draggable. DragSource is a higher-order component accepting three required parameters. They are described in detail below.

[DragSource Documentation](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drag-source.html)

On each documentation page, you can find examples in ES7, ES6, and ES5.

I hope this helps :).